# Module not found error when importing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import * from a file classes.py. My directory is as follows

```
mypkg
├── main.py
├── classes.py
```

When I try

```
from classes import *
```

It does not recognise classes. Looking it up I saw that I should use the explicit import

```
from .classes import *
```

which does recognise classes but gives the error below when I try to run it.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.classes'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Any advice on what to do and why this is happening would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: How and from what directory do you run your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `python` to recognize a folder as a package, you need an `__init__.py` file in it:

```
mypkg
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── classes.py
```

The directory where `python` is invoked is also important (running from inside a package folder is different to running from outside), and there's the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable as well.

The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/import.html) as a section on `import` and the package system, with good explanations.

Comment: For Python 3.3+ you don't need __init__ any more (if it would be empty anyway).